# (node:19980) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///{path}/build/index.html

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

A couple of months ago, I followed [This guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/node/integrations/electron-cra/) to create an electron application with react. Everything worked and I pushed the code to my respository as a bolierplate so that I can use it in the future.
Now, I start the project and get

`(node:19980) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///{path}/build/index.html`

I don't have build folder and I assume it will be created when I build for production.

I don't know what's wrong with it or I am missing something. Here is the package.json file.

```
 {
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "name": "react-electron-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "craco build",
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^23.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

My `electron.js` file code

```
const electron = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
let mainWindow;
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false },
  });
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  console.log(__dirname);
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"));
}
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

Here is the [link to the respository](https://github.com/Sanan4li/React-Electron-Boilerplate) having the complete code.